# Can I access TimeMachine data from a machine other than the one that was being backed up?

Tags: time-machine

I have an iMac with a dead internal drive. And I have it's TimeMachine drive. I'd like to know that the TimeMachine-based data is safe and sound so I'd like to restore it to my MBPro. But not *over top* of my MBPro data.

Is it possible to connect the iMac's TM drive to the MBPro and rebuild my Documents folder in to a random location (not over top of the MBPro's Documents folder) on my MBPro?

Comment: TimeMachine would totally miss his target if it wouldn't be possible, don't you think ?

Comment: @Pierre W: Not really. Apple makes no claims the data is stored in a format that'll be accessible piecemeal from any other machine. Thankfully it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can navigate your backup drive in the Finder. 
Mount it, go to the Backup folder > [name of machine] > [name of volume] > latest > Users > [user name] and restore the files you want.

(You can also choose a date instead of latest to restore earlier versions of the files/files that have been deleted.)

Comment: Look at that. Very cool. It's all there, safe and sound. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Time Machine UI to restore from the backups of a different Mac by option-clicking the Time Machine icon in your menubar or right-clicking the Time Machine icon in your Dock, and selecting "Browse Other Time Machine Disks".  (See [question 17 from the Time Machine FAQ](http://web.me.com/pondini/Time_Machine/17.html) for more details.)  You'll still need to navigate to "Latest" (or an earlier backup) as [zevlag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2952/zevlag) describes in his answer if you choose to do this.

If you do elect to use the *comfort* of Time Machine to choose what to restore, you'll want to read [question 16 from the FAQ: "How can I restore a file/folder to an alternate location?"](http://web.me.com/pondini/Time_Machine/16.html)